# How to perform massive data uploads to firebase firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I have about ~300mb of data (~180k json objects) that gets updated once every 2-3 days.

This data is divided into three "collections", that I must keep up to date.

I decided to take the Node.JS way, but any solution in a language i know ( Java, Python) will be welcomed.

Whenever I perform a batch set using the node.JS **firebase-admin** client, not only it consumes an aberrant amount of ram ( about 4-6GB!), but it also tends to crash with errors that don't have a clear ( up to page 4 of google search without a meaningful answer ) reason.

My code is frankly simple, this is it:

```
var collection = db.collection("items");
var batch = db.batch();

array.forEach(item => {
   var ref = collection.doc(item.id);
   batch.set(ref, item);
});

batch.commit().then((res) => {
    console.log("YAY",res);
});
```

I haven't found anywhere if there is a limit on the number of writes in a limited span of time (I understand doing 50-60k writes should be easy peasy with a backend the size of firebase), and also found that this can go up the ram train and have like 4-6GB of ram allocated.

I can confirm that when the errors are thrown, or the ram usage clogs my laptop, whatever happens first, I am still at less than 1-4% my daily usage quotas, so that is not the issue.

Comment: hove many items do you have in the array?

Comment: depends on the datasource, from 20K to 80K

Comment: There is a limit on the batch of 500 I think? Heres is a mention of it here: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-java/issues/106

Comment: i haven't seen that on any documentation @DauleDK. that might be it then.. is it 500 or 499?

Comment: I would say 500. The really good question is what happens if you create multiple batches in parallel. If coded in Nodejs I would use https://github.com/caolan/async to create a queue. Then you could experiment with hitting the limits here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas.

Comment: i might also be hitting: "Maximum writes per second per database (at beta) 2,500 (up to 2.5 MiB per second)"

Comment: will check that and inform you if it worked.

Comment: @DauleDK Thanks for your help here! It sounds like those limits and the link to the quota page were what was needed. Can you write it up into an answer?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen sure! I will do that when I have the time :)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen is there any reason behind the high ram usage, though? today i'll be testing the "chunk data in pieces of 500" way.

Comment: @DauleDK it did work, atleast way better than before. i'm still hitting the limits thought. you can post an answer any time you want so i can accept it.